# Integrate over triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Integrate $f(x,y) = (x+y+1)^{-2}$ over the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (4,0), (0,8)$.

I think you have to split up the triangle into different equations: $x=0, y=0, y=2x-8$. But I'm not sure what to do with these equations and how to relate them to the bounds of the double integral.

Answer (score 1):

So you've got $0\leq x\leq 4$ in one variable, and $0\leq y \leq 8-2x$ on the other. You have to make sure to integrate with respect to $y$ first in this case, since $y$ depends on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{2x-8} f(x,y) \,dy\,dx $$

---